# Is it possible to make energy potions on NA/EU?

Tags: black-desert-online

I have read that in other locales of Black Desert Online, it is possible for players to create energy potions by spending their own energy at approximately a 10:1 rate (i.e. spend 100 energy to create a potion that restores 10 energy).

Can players create energy potions in the NA/EU version of BDO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, you need to go to Velia and talk to the alchemist (Alustin). He will trade 50 energy for a 10 energy potion.